# Designing a triac based regulatable DC supply

Tags: triac, ac-dc, variable, diac

I need about (30V-160V)32A DC for my project. I am trying to build an electronic circuit to regulate AC mains (220V, 50Hz) to produce voltage from 30V to 160V and rectify it to produce DC voltage. With some inspiration from circuit diagrams posted online, I have designed my circuit (Enclosed)[image]
Kindly comment on my method and if possible help me improve my design.

Stay safe!

Edit 1 Note.
1. The required output DC 50-160V 32A, 8 Hour duty, 2. The available input 3 Phase AC 415V, 24A per phase 3. I have got a few BTA 41, some heat sinks, some 470Kohm potentiometers, KBPC3510 diode blocks, and 10 DB3 and 10K ohm resistor each.

Comment: without loss of generality: unless you know your DC load very well, probably a very bad idea.

Comment: by the way: up to 5.12 kW of output power is no joke, I hope you know how to keep your semiconductors cool enough.

Comment: You do realize that a BTA41 needs round about 50 mA gate trigger current. That has to be sourced via your 500 k pot in series with a 10 k resistor = lots of smoke (unless you have some magical or cunning plan that is so-far undisclosed).

Comment: What's the max allowable ripple voltage on your DC output?

Comment: @MarcusMüller my load is mostly resistive and very little capacitance and inductance. I intend to keep my semiconductors cool with large heat sinks and a fan mounted to the housing cabinet. What would you suggest I do? I have no formal electrical or electronics education, I am planning on using this for my electrodeposition research.

Comment: @peufeu The choice of the capacitance of the capacitor to filter is still open, My load is mostly resistance (electrodeposition) what capacitance would you suggest for this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to be aware of with this approach.

- It is not isolated. The output must be considered live.

[image]

*Figure 1. Phase-angle and output current into a linear load. Source: [Dimmers for LEDs](http://lednique.com/bulbs/dimmers-for-leds/).

- Voltage will increase as the dimmer trigger delay decreases from 180° to 90°.
- Once you reach the 90° the rectifier and smoothing capacitor will give peak voltage output of \$ 220 \sqrt 2 \$. Unless you have a large load to quickly discharge the capacitor you won't see much variation in voltage between 90° and 0° because the bridge rectifier will be reverse biased.
- To limit the voltage to 160 V you will have to limit the minimum resistance on the pot.
- Your most likely failure is of triac short-circuit. This will apply full mains voltage to the rectifier and will blow the capacitor if not adequately rated. Loss of the dimmer capacitor would also tend to switch the triac on early.

I'd be very careful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you like to suggest an improved circuit for this application or recommend I make any changes?

Comment: also, What do you think the efficiency of such a circuit would be?

Comment: Improved circuit: variable switched mode power supply or a variac instead of the dimmer. Efficiency with a triac is high because it's either off (P = 0) or fully on with a voltage drop of a volt or so.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use this in my lab. Our department says we would use only up to 16 A per phase and I need at least 30A for my experiment. So is there a way we could make it a 3 phase version?

Comment: Start with a proper specification. (1) Required output, voltage, current, stability, ripple, etc. (2) Electrical isolation. (3) Available supply. (4) Budget. (5) Anything else that might affect design.

Comment: 1. The required output  DC 50-160V 32A, 8 Hour duty, 
2. The available input 3 Phase AC 415V, 24A per phase
3. I have got a few BTA 41, some heat sinks, some 470Kohm potentiometers, KBPC3510 diode blocks, and 10 DB3 and 10K ohm resistor each.

Comment: That information belongs in the question - not buried in the comments. Hit the edit link ...